# SSH for loop: parameter passed to function captured in variable is not expanded

Tags: bash, ssh, for, command-substitution, variable-substitution

I have several servers which have several files with deploy date info I need to parse, and get a local copy of the files which are 2 months old or older.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# split on new line not space
# don't want to quote everything
# globbing desired
IFS=$'\n'

servers=(
  blue
  red
)

parseDate() {
    grep 'deploy_date:' $file | \
    sed  ...                  | \
    # much more in here...
}

getOldFiles() {
    local #all vars
    currentDateInSecs=$(date +%s)
    twoMonthsInSecs=526000
    for server in ${servers[@]}; do
        oldfile=$(
          ssh $server "
            $(declare -f parseDate)
            for file in /dir/$server/file*; do
                dateInSecs=$(date -jf '%b/%e/%Y' $(parseDate) +%s)
                timeDiff=$((\$currentDateInSecs - \$dateInSecs))
                ((\$timeDiff >= \$twoMonthsInSecs)) &&
                    cat \$file
            done
          "
        )
        [ -n $oldFile ] &&
            cat $oldFile ~/oldFiles/${server}-${file}.txt
    done
```

#### Problem:

Current issue is with `dateInSecs=$(date -jf '%b/%e/%Y' $(parseDate \$file) +%s)`.

When `parseDate \$file` is in `$()`
the `$file` variable is not expanded, it works fine without command substitution, but I need it.

How do I fix this?

#### Info:

<strike>This isn't a script, they're in my ~/.bash_profile</strike>

This is a script (among other scripts) in a git repo which is sourced from `~/bash_profile` (I have an install script which sets sources using `$PWD`) so people can use these commands directly instead of cd'ing to the git repo (which has many other things not applicable to the them).

Runs from Macos to CentOS servers.

Comment: made updates for clarity.

Comment: The -j argument doesn't exist for date command

Comment: If `ssh $server "$(declare -f parseDate); ..."` works, you could make it easier for yourself by putting the rest of the script passed to ssh also in a function. In general I would avoid trying to shove scripts like that inside the command line arg of ssh. But if you do that, you need to prevent the local shell from processing the command substitutions and arithmetic too.

Comment: @EdgarCivil it does on [macOS and BSD](https://man.openbsd.org/date). However, that's a valid point, the `date` on the CentOS machine won't have it, most likely. That will be the next problem. Nickotine, are you _sure_ your `date -jf '%b/%e/%Y'` command works when not in the `$()`? Have you installed BSD `date` on the CentOS server?

Comment: TIL `fn() { echo thing; }; ssh remoteHost "$(declare -f fn); fn"`. Wild!

Comment: Instead of all these issues you're having with quoting due to trying to call what's essentially a shell script via the command line of ssh, why don't you simply write the script for local execution and then transfer it to the remote machine. You may then execute it much easier.

Comment: @terdon -jf seems to return all the correct dates, I got lucky I guess, I'll recheck though

Comment: @ilkkachu this is actually a script which is sourced by `~/.bash_profile` from the git repo I'm on, I made it this way so people don't have to cd to the repo (the repo has a lot of things not applicable to them)

Comment: Nickotine the normal approach would be a directory of scripts that's added to people's `$PATH`. This is shell independent as no-one needs to `source` anything

Comment: Damn... I should've just had a script that does `echo "PATH=$PATH:$PWD/myScriptDir" ~/.bash_profile`? I want it do be automated as people are lazy would that work? Right now I have a script which has several `echo "$PWD/<script>" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: actually no as I don't want to tun the scripts only the functions and some source functions from other scriors

Comment: sorry `echo ". $PWD/<script>" >> ~/.bash_profile` then the functions become cmds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything that can be expanded inside your `oldfile=$(...)` command substitution is being expanded *before* you ssh. You need to escape the various internal `$()` if you want them to run on the remote instead of the local. Anything you want to be evaluated on the remote, needs escaping. Try:

```bash
oldfile=$(
          ssh $server "
            $(declare -f parseDate)
            for file in /dir/$server/file*; do
                dateInSecs=\$(date -jf '%b/%e/%Y' \$(parseDate \$file) +%s)
                timeDiff=\$(($currentDateInSecs - \$dateInSecs))
                ((\$timeDiff >= \$twoMonthsInSecs)) &&
                    cat \$file
            done
          "
        )
```

Also, while BSD `date` has the `-j` option, GNU `date` does not. Since your are connecting to a CentOS machine, you probably want to change

```
dateInSecs=\$(date -jf '%b/%e/%Y' \$(parseDate \$file) +%s)
```

to

```
dateInSecs=\$(date \$(parseDate \$file) +%s)
```

But we would need to see the exact format you get from `parseDate` to be sure.

Comment: and they need to _not_ escape the ones they want to expand locally, like `$server`, but also`$currentDateInSecs`

Comment: @ilkkachu ah yes, good catch, I missed that `$currentDateInSecs` is defined in the local.

Comment: I might've tried escaping all the $() but I'll retry

Comment: Think this will work just noticed what you did with the variable, thanks will try tomorrow

Comment: also had to use gnu `date` which was much easier to work with.

Comment: I had to move the stuff you had in the variable to a function as I got a syntax error, works all good now thanks, didn't know I needed to do `=\$` apart from that I also appreciate all the other knowledge. Couldn't have solved this without your answer and thanks for just answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with your double and single quotes. Where you use double quotes, all `$variables` and `$( … )` expressions will be evaluated before the command is executed. For example:

> ```
> ssh $server "
>     $(declare -f parseDate)
>     for file in /dir/$server/file*; do
>         dateInSecs=$(date -jf '%b/%e/%Y' $(parseDate \$file) +%s)
>         timeDiff=$((\$currentDateInSecs - \$dateInSecs))
>         ((\$timeDiff >= \$twoMonthsInSecs)) && cat \$file
>     done
> "
> ```

Here, if `$server` is `remoteHost`, this will be prepared as something like this *before* being passed through `ssh` to the remote `$server`:

```
ssh remoteHost "
    parseDate() { … }
    for file in /dir/remoteHost/file*; do
        dateInSecs=
        timeDiff=
        ((\$timeDiff >= \$twoMonthsInSecs)) && cat \$file
    done
"
```

And on the remoteHost itself, you'll try to execute something like this:

```
    parseDate() { … }
    for file in /dir/remoteHost/file*; do
        dateInSecs=
        timeDiff=
        (( >= )) && cat $file
    done
```

If you can amend your question to include an explanation of what you're trying to achieve, along with example input and output, someone here may be able to suggest how to rewrite your code to fit the requirements.

Comment: That should probably be `(($timeDiff >= $twoMonthsInSecs)) && cat $file` on the last line. But anyway, `$((\$currentDateInSecs - \$dateInSecs))` already croaks with a syntax error on Bash, so the whole `ssh` command won't run.

Comment: If I could avoid wrapping the ssh cmd in quotes it would make things so much easier... I can't use a heredoc as the stuff is in a function. Is there something else I can wrap the ssh cmd in?

Comment: @Nickotine if you amend your question to include an explanation of what you're trying to achieve, along with example input and output, someone here may be able to suggest how to modify your code